# Cannot find KDC for realm "[Domain Name]" while run docker image in linux container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have created docker image which will run on aws farget with linux operating system.

When I run localy it works fine but when I run docker image on container it will give me

Following error:

Cannot find KDC for realm "[Domain Name]".

The issue is in local it can find the domain but when it runs on container, not able to find local domain for authentication!

Any help or leads will be very much appreciated.

Thanks